# How to creat an array (k,1) of ordered pairs from an array (k,2)?

Tags: arrays, matlab

For example I have:
[1 3; 2 4; 2 5; 3 3]
and would like to have:
[(1,3);(2,4);(2,5);(3,3)]

I actually need to take two arrays (k,2) and count how many pairs are the same.
for example if I have:
A = [1 3; 2 4; 2 5; 3 5] and B = [2 3; 2 1; 2 4; 3 5]
I want the answer to be 2. 
Since as a sets (each of 4 ordered pairs), 
the intersection of A and B contains two elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know how many rows of `A` coincide with rows of `B`, use [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `'rows'` option:

```
sum(ismember(A, B, 'rows'))
```

For example:

```
>> A = [1 3; 2 4; 2 5; 3 5];
>> B = [2 3; 2 1; 2 4; 3 5];
>> sum(ismember(A, B, 'rows'))
ans =
     2
```

Comment: consider this test case `A = [1 3; 2 4; 2 3; 3 5] ; B = [2 3; 2 1; 2 4; 3 5;2 3];n1=sum(ismember(A,B,'rows'));n2=sum(ismember(B,A,'rows'));` which one is correct:`n1`? `n2`? `min(n1,n2)`? `max(n1,n2)`?

Comment: I tried it and n2 gives error. n1 gives 3 which is what i need. thanks!

Comment: @rahnema1 If `A` and `B` are (row-wise) considered as _sets_ (as the OP says), they shouln't contain duplicate rows, and then both `n1`  and `n2` would give the same result. Or use `intersect(A,B,'rows')` to automatically deduplicate